# What will local_auth choose by default if my device support face and fingerprint auth in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, in my application, I have to provide biometric authentication for sign in but local says there is a biometric type finger only available.

I am using Samsung m31 and in Kotak Mahindra bank application they allow me to use a finger as well as face option.

Why local_auth not giving face option?

And what will it choose by default if any device has both options face and finger?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the available biometric check for the mobile using the following code

```dart
List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics = await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
```

Android `local_auth` uses `BiometricPrompt` and it does not support Face unlock in Android 9. You can read more about it [here](https://source.android.com/security/biometric#android9) 
You can use `sensitiveTransaction` parameter to set the sensitivity of the transaction which handles `setConfirmationRequired()` in Android to enable Face lock for the supported device. You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#no-explicit-user-action)
Kotak Bank app is a native application that gives android SDK features directly to access all available biometric locks but in the case of Flutter, developers are dependent on the implementation of the plugin. You can probably enhance the implementation as per your requirement.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with Samsung S10 (Android 11) where both fingerprints and face recog. are available but the plugin only returns fingerprint as available option. You mentioned `sensitiveTransaction` but that can only be used with `auth.authenticate()` there is no workaround for `auth.getAvailableBiometrics()`